# If an object's motion through space-time at speed $c$ corresponds to ageing, would cooling it down to slow ageing mean it doesn't move at $c$?

Tags: spacetime, temperature

I get that all objects must move at the speed of light (c) in their reference frame because of the 2-part vector of space-time.  For a case where the vector is pointing directly at time (because it is not moving in space) I saw someone use the example of an apple "aging" as it sits still.  OK, but to me "aging" is fundamentally just the rearranging of atoms due to biological processes.  If the apple (or a particle for that matter) is cooled down near absolute zero, it seems that the "aging" is reduced and with the apple not moving in space, how can this still equal c?

Comment: The ageing analogy is pretty bad. Just forget about it. Things do travel at speed $c$ through space time, but this is independent of the biological notion of ageing.

Comment: A particle traveling at $c$ doesn't experience any proper time, so the idea of "aging" doesn't apply to it...

Comment: He's mixing up some terminology - the magnitude of the velocity 4-vector of any object is $c$. He's not actually talking about an object moving with speed $c$.

Comment: Biological aging and physical aging are two different things. If you set a rock next to the apple, it won't biologically age even if it's warm, but it's still moving through spacetime with the same 4-vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you measure that it takes an apple 2 days to rot, then you note that another apple (which happens to be colder) takes 3 days to rot, you could either conclude that time has slowed down, or that the rotting of an apple does not make a very reliable clock.

I conclude the latter.

A cold apple and a hot apple are both experiencing the same passage of time...it's just that in one the mold spores/bacteria don't grow as quickly because they're cold.

---

A separate note on terminology:

it's fun to think of all objects moving with a speed of $c$ through spacetime, but it's a somewhat misleading statement. There is an object called the "velocity 4-vector" which is useful for transforming the velocity of an object from one reference frame to another, and it's true that the magnitude of that vector is always $c$, but the magnitude of the velocity 4-vector cannot be interpreted as "speed" in the same way as the magnitude of the familiar classical velocity vector. Thus, your statement,

> I get that all objects must move at the speed of light (c) in their reference frame

is self-contradictory and false. Objects do not move at all in their own reference frame, by definition.